# How to send mail from powershell without giving username and password details from a server which is in domain and it is logged in as service account

Tags: powershell, sendmail

I tried send-mailmessage with no luck.
I tried with New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient() with no luck
thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error with `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet?

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried. Also, explain what didn't work and if you received error messages, show them in full aswell. Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62517086/edit) link to update your question with this information. Without it, it is just a guessing game..

Comment: Any resource target which is configured to require auth, you must explicitly provide it either you current logged on user session, or passed in. If you do not know the creds, which for service accounts, you would not, then of course they can't be passed. PowerShell always runs in the user contact that started it. If you are running a script using a General/MA/gMSA service account, then it is prudent that this is a scheduled task candidate. I've never seen any use cases for a service account to have interactive logon. Interactive logon means typing creds via the Windows host login UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Agree with @Theo, it would be helpful if you build up the question a little.  That said, if you are using `Send-MailMessage` it'll use windows authentication, meaning the username & password of the user running the process.  In an Exchange environment (which I assume you mean by "domain"), this often causes issues because the user doesn't have rights to submit mail.  A quick workaround is to create a anonymous credential and cite it in the `Send-MailMessage` command.  That would look something like:

```
$Pass = New-Object System.Security.SecureString
$Creds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON", $Pass

Send-MailMessage -To Someone@somewhere.com From Me@myplace.com -Subject "Test" -SmtpServer mySMTPServer.myorg.com -Credential $Cred
```

You can read a bit about the issue [here](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/ask_the_experts/f/learn_powershell_from_don_jones-24/11843/send-mailmessage-without-authentication) , Note: I'm Nashiooka in that conversation.

A slightly more concise version, using some newer conventions:

```
$Cred = [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::new( 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON', [System.Security.SecureString]::New() )

Send-MailMessage -To Someone@somewhere.com From Me@myplace.com -Subject "Test" -SmtpServer mySMTPServer.myorg.com -Credential $Cred
```

Obviously you should update with your own information.